# Can we use more than 1 style for ttk.Notebook (tkinter), such as "tab.TNotebook" and "background.TNotebook"?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried using both separately and they work, but when I combine them under the same variable neither of them work. Is there a method of combining them both together?
Here is the bit of my code which I am talking about:

---

```
sideTab = ttk.Style(screen)
sideTab.configure("tab.TNotebook", tabposition='wn')
tabColour = ttk.Style(screen)
tabColour.configure("colour.TNotebook", background="black")

newStyle = ("tab.TNotebook", "colour.TNotebook")

tabList = ttk.Notebook(screen, style=newStyle)
```

---

This code wouldn't change the style as both are being used in the 'style'
Does anyone have any ideas how I could get them both to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually enough to create a single `ttk.Style` instance and configure the styles of all the  widgets with it.

To combine styles, just choose one name, e.g. "custom.TNotebook" and configure the same options as in "colour.TNotebook" and "tab.TNotebook":

```
style.configure("custom.TNotebook", background="black", tabposition="nw")
```

and use this style for your notebook.

Full example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.configure("custom.TNotebook", background="black", tabposition='wn')

tabList = ttk.Notebook(root, style="custom.TNotebook")
for i in range(4):
    tabList.add(ttk.Label(tabList, text=f"Content {i}"), text=f"Tab {i}")
tabList.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```